# Does spark-submit --master --local[4] limit whole app to 4 cores, or just spark workers?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a tensorflow program I want to run on the master node of a AWS EMR cluster that only has a very light spark dependency - I want to do a spark submit command to makes as much resources available to tensorflow as possible. I was thinking that if I did

```
spark-submit --master local[4] myprogram.py
```

That spark would only get 4 cores, and `myprogram.py` would get the rest - but maybe I am limited the number of cores to the whole application to only 4? (Say the master node has 32 cores)

The tensorflow program is not distributed - the whole flow is a big spark app that does a lot of ETL with task nodes, then the training just happens on the master node, but the training still uses spark a bit -- that is the awkwardness - ordinarily I would make my own python environment for tensorflow and pyspark, but since I'm on EMR, I don't want to manage two spark installations.

Comment: I think the whole app will be limited to 4 cores. But you need to be aware of the running components of the app itself. For example, if you use Spark Streaming, you will implicitly have "the receiver" alongside your app, which means that you need to assign at least 2 cores to the whole app - one for receiver, one for your logic. otherwise, the receiver would take over a single core, leaving no resource for your logic

Answer (score 1):

With `spark-submit --master local[4] myprogram.py`, Run Spark locally with 4 worker threads.

Even if your cluster has 32 cores, spark application will utilize 4 cores only.

The deployment will be non-distributed single-JVM deployment mode, Spark spawns all the execution components - `driver, executor, LocalSchedulerBackend, and master` - in the same single **JVM**.

The `number of tasks` to be launched is controlled by the number of threads as specified in **master URL**. In your case number of tasks will be 4.

Comment: The spark application utilizes 4 cores - and since master is part of the spark application - it sounds like if I do some non spark tensorflow linear algebra in the master program it will only see 4 cores - thanks!